# Java change the periodTime of a timer.schdule

Tags: java

So i just found out about this thing called a timer.schedule(). I played around with it a bit and i fell over a problem. I want to be able to change the period- time for the schedule for each time the task is ran.
I did not include all code but from what i think no more then the code written here should be enough to get the concept. I have menu of JSliders where I put up a few values. Theese value are supposed to represent the periodTime of the task. I then put the values in an arrayList of integers wich i try to use to refer to the different values. However the schedule just locks it self to its first value. If anyone have an idea of how i can solve this i would be more then happy to hear your solutions

```
public static ArrayList <JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
public static ArrayList <JSlider> sliderList = new ArrayList<JSlider>();
public static ArrayList <Integer> timeLapse = new ArrayList<Integer>();

if(sliderList.size() > 1){
for(int i = 0; i < sliderList.size();i++){
timeLapse.add(sliderList.get(i).getValue());
```

}

```
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
            { 
                public void run() {
                    if(currentColor == Color.red){
                        currentColor = Color.green;
                        System.out.println("Start");
                        music(startSound);
                        frame.setBackground(currentColor);
                        game.repaint();
                    }else if(currentColor == Color.green){
                        currentColor = Color.red;
                        System.out.println("stop");
                        music(stopSound);
                        frame.setBackground(currentColor);
                        game.repaint();
                    }
                } 
            },0, timeLapse.get(timeLapseCounter)*(1000*1));
            timeLapse.clear();


        }
```

Comment: Which line has the unexpected behavior? Where do you update timeLapseCounter?

Comment: Oh so i didn't get that part in im sry. I tried to increment timeLapseCounter in both the if and else if statement. But it will stick to the first element in the timeLapse ArrayList anyway. Atleast that is how it worked for me

Comment: I figure that i need some sort of an update metod for it maybe... but i have no idea how to. Tried both a whileloop and for loop